# Cliente Servidor erro no envio de mensagens

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte codigo porem quando corro o Servidor e o cliente e tento enviar mensagens a partir do cliente (Frame janelaUtilizador) da me erro! Alguem consegue me ajudar?
Supostamente o erro esta a classe Painel mensagens no botaoEnviar no actionlistener

```
public class PainelMensagens extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private EstadoMensagem estadoMensagem = null;
private JButton botaoEnviar;
private JTextField zonaEscreverMensagens;
private JTextArea zonaReceberMensagens;
private JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador;


private Mensagem mensagem;
private SocketCliente socketCliente;


public PainelMensagens(JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador) {
    this.janelaUtilizador = janelaUtilizador;

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    criarPainelEscrita();
    criarPainelLeitura();
}


private void criarPainelEscrita(){
    JPanel painelEscrita = new JPanel();
    painelEscrita.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    zonaEscreverMensagens = new JTextField();

    botaoEnviar = new JButton("Enviar");
    botaoEnviar.addActionListener(e->{
        String texto = this.zonaEscreverMensagens.getText();
        String nome = this.mensagem.getNome();

        if(!texto.isEmpty()){
        this.mensagem = new Mensagem();
        this.mensagem.setNome(nome);
        this.mensagem.setMensagem(texto);
        this.mensagem.setAccao(Accao.ENVIAR_TODOS);

        this.socketCliente.enviar(this.mensagem);
        }
        this.zonaEscreverMensagens.setText("");
    });


    painelEscrita.add(zonaEscreverMensagens, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    painelEscrita.add(botaoEnviar, BorderLayout.EAST);

    add(painelEscrita, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


private void criarPainelLeitura(){
    zonaReceberMensagens = new JTextArea();
    zonaReceberMensagens.setEditable(false);

    add(zonaReceberMensagens, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}




public EstadoMensagem getEstadoMensagem() {
    return estadoMensagem;
}

public JTextField getZonaEscreverMensagens() {
    return zonaEscreverMensagens;
}

public JTextArea getZonaReceberMensagens() {
    return zonaReceberMensagens;
}

public JanelaUtilizador getJanelaUtilizador() {
    return janelaUtilizador;
}

public JButton getBotaoEnviar() {
    return botaoEnviar;
}
}
```

---

```
public class PainelEstadoContacto extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador;
private JButton botaoOnline;
private JButton botaoOffline;
private JTextField nomeUtilizador;


private Socket socket;
private Mensagem mensagem;
private SocketCliente socketCliente;


public PainelEstadoContacto(JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador) {
    this.janelaUtilizador=janelaUtilizador;

    botaoOnline= new JButton("ONLINE");
    botaoOnline.addActionListener(e -> {
        String nome = nomeUtilizador.getText();

        if(!nome.isEmpty()){
            this.mensagem = new Mensagem();
            this.mensagem.setAccao(Accao.ONLINE);
            this.mensagem.setNome(nome);

            this.socketCliente = new SocketCliente();
            this.socket = this.socketCliente.conectar();

            //Criar thread para iniciar processo
            new Thread(new ListenerSocket(this.socket)).start();
        }
        this.socketCliente.enviar(mensagem);

    });

    botaoOffline=new JButton("OFFLINE");
    botaoOffline.addActionListener(e->{
        this.mensagem.setAccao(Accao.OFFLINE);
        this.socketCliente.enviar(this.mensagem);
        desconectar(mensagem);
    });

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    painel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel utilizador = new JLabel("Utilizador:");
    nomeUtilizador = new JTextField();

    painel.add(utilizador, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    painel.add(nomeUtilizador, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    add(painel);

    add(botaoOnline);
    add(botaoOffline);
}


public JanelaUtilizador getJanelaUtilizador() {
    return janelaUtilizador;
}


private class ListenerSocket implements Runnable {
    private ObjectInputStream input ; 

    public ListenerSocket(Socket socket) {
        try {
            this.input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Mensagem mensagem = null;

        try {
            while((mensagem = (Mensagem) input.readObject()) != null){
                Accao accao =  mensagem.getAccao();                 //receber accao por parte do servidor

                if(accao.equals(accao.ONLINE)){
                    conectado(mensagem);
                }else if(accao.equals(accao.OFFLINE)){
                    desconectar(mensagem);
                    socket.close();
                }else if(accao.equals(accao.ENVIAR_UM)){
                    receberMensagem(mensagem);
                }else if(accao.equals(accao.CONTACTOS_ONLINE)){
                    atualizarLista(mensagem);
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private void conectado(Mensagem mensagem){
    if(mensagem.getMensagem().equals("Não conectado!")){
        this.nomeUtilizador.setText("");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Conexão sem sucesso \n Introduzir outro nome");
        return ;
    }
    this.mensagem = mensagem;
    //      this.botaoOnline.setEnabled(false);
    //      this.nomeUtilizador.setEditable(false);
    //
    //      this.botaoOffline.setEnabled(true);
    //      
    //      //this.textoEnviado.setEditable(true);
    //      this.janelaUtilizador.getPainelMensagens().getZonaEscreverMensagens().setEditable(true);
    //      
    //      //this.botaoEnviar.setEnabled(true);
    //      this.janelaUtilizador.getPainelMensagens().getBotaoEnviar().setEnabled(true);
    //      //this.botaoAtualizarLista.setEnabled(true);
    //      this.janelaUtilizador.getPainelMensagens()

    //this.textoRecebido.append(mensagem.getNome() + "\n");
    this.janelaUtilizador.getPainelMensagens().getZonaReceberMensagens().append(mensagem.getNome() + "\n");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Conectado ao QuequeAPP");
}

private void desconectar(Mensagem mensagem){

    this.botaoOnline.setEnabled(true);
    this.nomeUtilizador.setEditable(true);

    this.botaoOffline.setEnabled(false);
    //      this.textoEnviado.setEditable(false);
    //      this.botaoEnviar.setEnabled(false);
    //      this.botaoApagar.setEnabled(false);
    //      this.botaoAtualizarLista.setEnabled(false);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "OFFLINE");
}

private void receberMensagem(Mensagem mensagem){
    //      this.textoRecebido.append(mensagem.getNome() + " diz:" + mensagem.getMensagem() + "\n");
    this.janelaUtilizador.getPainelMensagens().getZonaReceberMensagens().append(mensagem.getNome() + " diz: " + mensagem.getMensagem() + "\n");
}

private void atualizarLista(Mensagem mensagem) {

}
}
```

---

```
public class JanelaUtilizador {

private PainelContactos painelContactos;
private PainelMensagens painelMensagens;
private PainelEstadoContacto painelEstadoContacto;
private JFrame janela;
private Cliente cliente;


public JanelaUtilizador(Cliente cliente){
    this.cliente = cliente;

    painelContactos = new PainelContactos(this);
    painelMensagens = new PainelMensagens(this);
    painelEstadoContacto = new PainelEstadoContacto(this);

    criarJanela();
    janela.validate();
    janela.setVisible(true);
}


public void criarJanela(){
    janela = new JFrame("QuequeApp");

    janela.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    janela.setLocation(400,100);
    janela.setSize(500, 500);

    janela.add(painelContactos, BorderLayout.WEST);
    janela.add(painelMensagens, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    janela.add(painelEstadoContacto, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
}



public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public JFrame getJanela() {
    return janela;
}

public PainelContactos getPainelContactos() {
    return painelContactos;
}

public PainelMensagens getPainelMensagens() {
    return painelMensagens;
} 
}
```

Mensagem de erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Cliente Servidor erro a enviar mensagens](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102482/cliente-servidor-erro-a-enviar-mensagens)

Comment: Então por que apagou, se não era duplicata?

Comment: So agora e que percebi! Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Você postou código demais. Mas creio que dentro da classe PainelMensagens o objeto private SocketCliente socketCliente está nulo. Assim, quando vc chama ele dentro do seu  botaoEnviar.addActionListener dá o erro de NPE (Null Pointer Exception).

Comment: então e que valor e que tem de assumir? sabe?

Comment: Não tem que assumir valor. Tem que ser instanciado em algum lugar, de acordo com a sua lógica. Algo assim: this.socketCliente = new SocketCliente(). Exatamente como você faz com o campo mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro da classe **PainelMensagens**, método **criarPainelEscrita**, existe o código abaixo:

```
botaoEnviar.addActionListener(e->{
    String texto = this.zonaEscreverMensagens.getText();
    String nome = this.mensagem.getNome();

    if(!texto.isEmpty()){
    this.mensagem = new Mensagem();
    this.mensagem.setNome(nome);
    this.mensagem.setMensagem(texto);
    this.mensagem.setAccao(Accao.ENVIAR_TODOS);

    this.socketCliente.enviar(this.mensagem);
    }
    this.zonaEscreverMensagens.setText("");
});
```

Neste código, está sendo referenciado o objeto **socketCliente**, assim:

```
this.socketCliente.enviar(this.mensagem);
```

Entretanto, este campo não está sendo instanciado em nenhum lugar. Portanto, muito provavelmente, o seu NPE está sendo gerado por causa disso.

Para resolver, esse objeto precisa ser instanciado, da mesma maneira que você fez com o campo mensagem, algo assim:

```
this.socketCliente = new SocketCliente();
```

Note que estou omitindo qualquer parametros do construtor, se o mesmo existir.

Um outro erro pode ser visto na mesma rotina acima, porém no campo **mensagem**.

O seguinte trecho de código está sendo executado antes de instanciar o objeto mensagem, veja:

```
String nome = this.mensagem.getNome();
```

Comment: acho que entendi, então como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: eu meto esse this.socketCliente = new Cliente em cima do this.socketCliente.enviar(this.mensagem) e mesmo assim quando tento enviar uma mensagem da me o mesmo erro

Comment: NPE é um erro causado pelo programador. Portanto, você está deixando de instanciar algo e tentando referenciá-lo. Como a referência é nula, acontece isso. Se não tem relação com o que falei, faça um Debug que você encontrará facilmente.

Comment: sim tem razão essa parte eu entendi. Mas não consigo resolver o erro e é mesmo importante porque falta me este passo para o meu projecto estar completo, so tenho esse erro que não consigo mesmo resolver e sei que é fácil para vocês

Comment: vc tentou debugar o seu código? Coloca um breakpoint dentro do addActionListener e veja passo-a-passo em qual ponto desse trecho está dando o erro. Não temos como ajudar mais do que isso. Precisaríamos do código rodando e ainda entender a sua lógica. Por isso, as dúvidas precisam ter escopo muito bem delimitado.

Comment: Sim ja tentei eu sei que o erro e simples e que me consegue ajudar num minuto não consigo e explicar melhor

Comment: nao me pode dar o seu mail para me ajudar?

Comment: ultima dica: eu vi que no construtor da PainelEstadoContacto voce instancia um socketCliente assim: this.socketCliente = new SocketCliente(); this.socket = this.socketCliente.conectar(); Porque você não faz o mesmo na PainelMensagens?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32641/discussion-between-cantoni-and-java).